# Creating a for loop to loop through urls-(variable) from excel in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

1ST EDIT: As requested by 'Rivered' at the end of this question i ll be including my excel contents + some prints in pycharm.

I have searched for hours but i can't make it work. This is my first ever question.

What i am trying to do is loop through a bunch of urls in jupyter, and scrape the price of products. Here is my code. I am a complete begginer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url1 = "https://www.patman.gr/el/login?returnurl=%2f"
driver.get(url1)
driver.maximize_window()


cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"qc-cmp2-ui\"]/div[2]/div/button[2]")
cookie_button.click()

email_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"Email\"]")
email_login.click()
email_login.send_keys("My_email")

password_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"Password\"]")
password_login.click()
password_login.send_keys("My_password")

login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"form0\"]/div[3]/input")
login_button.click()


df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Hidden_user\Desktop\python folder\προχειρο σημειοματαρειο\coding.xlsx')



for line in df_xlsx:
    x = df_xlsx['url']
    driver.get(x)
    get_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span")
    print(get_price.text)
```

I was expecting for the program to run properly.

When i am trying to print out the variable 'x' from my excel in pycharm it prints properly.

If i put the variable 'x' in the driver.get() method the system gives me the following error

TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

here is the full error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 21
     19     x = df_xlsx['url']
     20 #     y = '"' + x + '"'
---> 21     driver.get(x)
     22     get_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span")
     23     print(get_price.text)

File ~\PycharmProjects\scraping_with_selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:441, in WebDriver.get(self, url)
    437 def get(self, url: str) -> None:
    438     """
    439     Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    440     """
--> 441     self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

File ~\PycharmProjects\scraping_with_selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:427, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    424         params['sessionId'] = self.session_id
    426 params = self._wrap_value(params)
--> 427 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    428 if response:
    429     self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File ~\PycharmProjects\scraping_with_selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py:342, in RemoteConnection.execute(self, command, params)
    340 if isinstance(params, dict) and 'sessionId' in params:
    341     del params['sessionId']
--> 342 data = utils.dump_json(params)
    343 url = f"{self._url}{path}"
    344 return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

File ~\PycharmProjects\scraping_with_selinium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\utils.py:23, in dump_json(json_struct)
     22 def dump_json(json_struct: Any) -> str:
---> 23     return json.dumps(json_struct)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py:231, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    226 # cached encoder
    227 if (not skipkeys and ensure_ascii and
    228     check_circular and allow_nan and
    229     cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    230     default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
--> 231     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py:199, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    195         return encode_basestring(o)
    196 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    197 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201     chunks = list(chunks)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py:257, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    252 else:
    253     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    254         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    255         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257 return _iterencode(o, 0)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py:179, in JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    160 def default(self, o):
    161     """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    162     a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    163     (to raise a ``TypeError``).
   (...)
    177 
    178     """
--> 179     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                     f'is not JSON serializable')

TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
```

I also tried

1)

```
for line in df_xlsx:
     urla = df_xlsx['url']
     urlo = '"' + urla + '"'
     print(df_xlsx[urlo])
```

I did this in case it needed the " "

2)

i tried updating my excel form by hardcoding the " " in the cells that contained urls
so for example, if th cell was saying :

https://www.google.com/

i updated it so it would say

"https://www.google.com/"

3)

i tried

df_xlsx = df_xlsx.to_json()

when i did that i got a different error saying:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 19
     16 df_xlsx = df_xlsx.to_json()    
     18 for line in df_xlsx:
---> 19     x = df_xlsx['url']
     20 #     y = '"' + x + '"'
     21     driver.get(x)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

4. 

i tried the previous steps as well while trying to read from a csv file, in case that worked
tldr it didn't

i ve spent 3 days on this problem and i cant understand why its not working

Any help would be really apreciated , thanks in advance for your time and knowledge

1ST EDIT:

contents of excel :(Can't post pictures yet so i am typing it out)

```
         A1      B1
    1 1601146   https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%84%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9-%CF%88%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%85-astrea-23mm-aspira-%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BD
    
    2 1601019   https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%81-crypton-r115-t110-05-alter
    
    3 1601025   https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%81-crypton-x135-%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B5
    
    4 1601120   https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%81-wave110i-%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%B5-%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%85%CE%BB
```

Pycharm code to print values in Column B:

```
    import pandas as pd
                 
    df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Black Cat\Desktop\python folder\προχειρο σημειοματαρειο\coding.xlsx')
                 
    for line in df_xlsx:
        x = df_xlsx['url']
        print(x)
```

Pycharm Output :

```
    "C:\Users\Black Cat\PycharmProjects\working_with_pandas\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Black Cat\PycharmProjects\working_with_pandas\main.py" 
    0    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF...
    1    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    2    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    3    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    Name: url, dtype: object
    0    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF...
    1    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    2    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    3    https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%CF...
    Name: url, dtype: object
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Pycharm code to inlude " " in the urls :

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Black Cat\Desktop\python folder\προχειρο σημειοματαρειο\coding.xlsx')
    
    for line in df_xlsx:
        urla = df_xlsx['url']
        urlo = '"' + urla + '"'
        print(urlo)
```

Pycharm output:

```
    "C:\Users\Black Cat\PycharmProjects\working_with_pandas\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Black Cat\PycharmProjects\working_with_pandas\main.py" 
    0    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%C...
    1    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    2    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    3    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    Name: url, dtype: object
    0    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BA%C...
    1    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    2    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    3    "https://www.patman.gr/el/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%85%C...
    Name: url, dtype: object
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you show for some what x prints out: ```for line in df_xlsx[0:10]:
    print( df_xlsx['url'] )```. In addition, if you perform ```driver.get("https://www.patman.gr/el/login?returnurl=%2f")``` does it give the expected output? Are you sure you need to use selenium, as most often just the requests() library is more then sufficient.

Comment: @Rivered Thank you for the quick answer, i wanted to let you know that i have updated the post with the info you required. To answer your questions: the program is behaving properly, the driver loads -->driver.get("https://www.patman.gr/el/login?returnurl=%2f") , accepts the cookie button, puts in email and password info and logs in. After it lands on the suppliers website, it then stops and jupyter gives me the posted errors. For your second question i dont know if selenium is mandatory, i am trying to do this from countless youtube videos